# Belkin router show LAN

Tags: router, lan

We just installed a Belkin wireless router. How do you view the Local Area Network? With our AT&T router, I could go to the setup page and view all the connected computers.

How do I do this with the Belkin router?

The model number is N150. Sorry about being so unclear.

Comment: Do you have any kind of model number? They have changed their web interface over the years.

Comment: You could otherwise spend time around in the router and look for stuff called DHCP List, Attached Devices, Wireless Clients, etc...

Comment: we need more info...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I googled

> Belkin N150 DHCP list

and this was the first result. It has your answer.

http://www.homenetworkingsupport.com/z/347022000000625

> You can view a list of the computers (known as clients), which are connected to your network. You are able to view the IP address (1) of the computer, the host name (2) (if the computer has been assigned one), and the MAC address (3) of the computer's network interface card (NIC). Pressing the "Refresh" (4) button will update the list. If there have been any changes, the list will be updated.

Comment: Something more than just a link would be helpful. Maybe a summary of the instructions the link provides?

Comment: Thank you so much! I still would like to know: Is there a way to change the name of the computers in the DHCP client list? With our old AT&T router, you could change the name of each of the computers.

Comment: This is a separate question as most of the times it pulls the actual computer name or device.